# Database not able to connect with server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hi everyone i am new to mysql and i am stuck and not able to connect to db using mysql font i want to create a db in that server

Here is what i am doing in connection

[image]

This is the error response i am getting

[image]

Can anyone suggest me the solution to this? what i need to change user,password and host are correct i have verified that

Comment: Your username and password is wrong.

Comment: @PraveenKumar but it is going good with filezilla in filezila it is opening with same username and password

Comment: @Sherry FileZilla is only for FTP, not MySQL. You should be using another one for MySQL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i am new to php and mysql i didn't understand what u said can you explain me please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the comments I conclude that you have problems understanding why your FTP password does not work for MySQL.

The reason this is is because you are talking to to totally different programs on the server and expect them to behave in the same way.

If you connect to another computer `ahcap.com` in your example, your connection is redirected to different programs running on the server based on the port number. For example a request arriving on the Port 21 is redirected to the FTP server program, which is responsible for showing you files on the server. The MySQL server program sits at another port (3306 in your example) and is responsible for answering your data requests from a data base.

Both programs are independent of one another and you talk to them in different languages (FileZilla can talk with the FTP server program and MySQL Font can talsk to the MySQL server program). Also they decide whether your password is correct based on their own settings and do not consider whether this password might be OK for another server program.

Therefore, you will need different usernames/passwords for them.

The person who runs the server computer **might** have set the passwords to be the same. But this can be decided freely, there is no technical reason why they must be the same. Look up the emails you exchanged with the person/company running the server computer, maybe you have diffferent usernames/passwords for FTP and MySQL

Comment: thank you very much i was confused in server and mysql accounts that is now cleared